About errors when using selenium headless
When launching a headless browser with selenium, a pure white window is forcibly displayed. This cannot be touched or moved, but the internal system is still running.
Please let me know if you know.
Change user agent
headless=new specified
Updated seleniumu to the latest version

Change to ('--headless=old'), and then it works.
